# pandas: comparing non-identical list of panda dataframes based on values from a certain column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, compare

I have a two lists of panda dataframes as follows,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
list_one = [pd.DataFrame({'sent_a.1': [0, 3, 2, 1], 'sent_a.2': [0, 1, 4, 0], 'sent_b.3': [0, 6, 0, 8],'sent_b.4': [1, 1, 8, 6],'ID':['id_1','id_1','id_1','id_1']}),
        pd.DataFrame({'sent_a.1': [0, 3], 'sent_a.2': [0, 2], 'sent_b.3': [0, 6],'sent_b.4': [1, 1],'ID':['id_2','id_2']})]

list_two = [pd.DataFrame({'sent_a.1': [0, 5], 'sent_a.2': [0, 1], 'sent_b.3': [0, 6],'sent_b.4': [1, 1],'ID':['id_2','id_2']}),
            pd.DataFrame({'sent_a.1': [0, 5, 3, 1], 'sent_a.2': [0, 2, 3, 1], 'sent_b.3': [0, 6, 6, 8],'sent_b.4': [1, 5, 8, 5],'ID':['id_1','id_1','id_1','id_1']})]
```

I would like to compare the dataframes in these two lists and if the values are the same, I would like to replace the value with 'True' and if the values are different, I would like to set them to 'False' and save the result in a different list of panda dataframes. I have done the following,

```
for dfs in list_one:
    for dfs2 in list_two:
       g = np.where(dfs == dfs2, 'True', 'False')
       print (g)
```

but I get the error,

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

how can I sort values in these two lists, based on the values from column 'ID'?

**Edit**
I would like the dataframes that have the same value for column 'ID' to be compared. meaning that dataframes that have 'ID' == 'id_1' are to be compared with one another and dataframes that have 'ID' == 'id_2' to be compared with each other (not a cross comparison)

so the desired output is:

```
output = [   sent_a.1  sent_a.2  sent_b.3  sent_b.4    ID
        0    True         True      True       True   id_1

        1    False        False     True       False  id_1

        2    False        False     False      True   id_1

        3    False        False     True       True   id_1, 
             sent_a.1  sent_a.2  sent_b.3  sent_b.4    ID
        0    True         True      True       True   id_2
        1    True         True      False      False  id_2]
```

Comment: How do you define equality here? Which columns do you want to consider? I would consider all dataframes to be different overall

Comment: I am comparing the dataframes in the lists based on the column names, and they should be ordered based on values in column 'ID'

Comment: they call the library pandas with s

Comment: what you want to do is unfortunately unclear, you should provide the expected output and clarify how **exactly** you want to perform the comparison

Comment: i added the edit, thank you for pointing it out

Comment: Is it normal you swap the order of dataframes between 2 lists?

Comment: my original lists are much larger than the example brought here an there are cases where they are not in order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your current example

For your first question:

> how can I sort values in these two lists, based on the values from column 'ID'?

```
list_one = sorted(list_one,key=lambda x: x['ID'].unique()[0][3:], reverse=False)
list_two =sorted(list_two,key=lambda x: x['ID'].unique()[0][3:], reverse=False)
```

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

- error due to different index values order in dataframes or dataframes are of different shapes

First way of comparison:

```
for dfs in list_one:
    for dfs2 in list_two:
        if dfs.shape == dfs2.shape:
            g = np.where(dfs == dfs2, 'True', 'False')
            print (g)
```

Second way:

> I would like the dataframes that have the same value for column 'ID' to be compared

```
for dfs in list_one:
    for dfs2 in list_two:
        if (dfs['ID'].unique() == dfs2['ID'].unique()) and (dfs.shape == dfs2.shape):
            g = np.where(dfs == dfs2, 'True', 'False')
            print (g)
```