# python(pandas): comparing list of pandas based on values in a column in pandas

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, compare

I have a two lists of panda dataframes as follows,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
list_one = [pd.DataFrame({'sent_a.1': [0, 3, 2, 1], 'sent_a.2': [0, 1, 4, 0], 'sent_b.3': [0, 6, 0, 8],'sent_b.4': [1, 1, 8, 6],'ID':['id_1_2','id_1_3','id_1_4','id_1_4']}),
        pd.DataFrame({'sent_a.1': [0, 3], 'sent_a.2': [0, 2], 'sent_b.3': [0, 6],'sent_b.4': [1, 1],'ID':['id_2_1','id_2_2']})]

list_two = [pd.DataFrame({'sent_a.1': [0, 5, 3, 1], 'sent_a.2': [0, 2, 3, 1], 'sent_b.3': [0, 6, 6, 8],'sent_b.4': [1, 5, 8, 5],'ID':['id_1_2','id_1_3','id_1_4','id_1_4']}),
            pd.DataFrame({'sent_a.1': [0, 5], 'sent_a.2': [0, 1], 'sent_b.3': [0, 6],'sent_b.4': [1, 1],'ID':['id_2_1','id_2_2']})]
```

I would like the dataframes that have the same value for column 'ID' to be compared. meaning that dataframes that have 'ID' == 'id_1' are to be compared with one another and dataframes that have 'ID' == 'id_2' to be compared with each other (not a cross comparison)

so the desired output is:

```
output = [   sent_a.1  sent_a.2  sent_b.3  sent_b.4    ID
        0    True         True      True       True   id_1_2

        1    False        False     True       False  id_1_3

        2    False        False     False      True   id_1_4

        3    False        False     True       True   id_1_5, 
             sent_a.1  sent_a.2  sent_b.3  sent_b.4    ID
        0    True         True      True       True   id_2_1
        1    True         True      False      False  id_2_2]
```

I have posted a similar question before, but realized that the answer [Dhage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71033943/pandas-comparing-non-identical-list-of-panda-dataframes-based-on-values-from-a) gave me here does not work if the 'ID' columns' values are slightly different. when I run the code I get, the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I tried changing the if line to,

```
if np.allclose(dfs['ID'].unique() == dfs2['ID'].unique()):
```

or

```
if (dfs['ID'].unique()).any() == (dfs2['ID'].unique()).any():
```

but I do not get the desired output.

**Edit**
ok, i tried the following and at least i get the bolean result ( not in a dataframe format though), and it sends the deprecation error

```
if np.any(dfs['ID'].unique() == dfs2['ID'].unique()):
```

the error is,

```
DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
```

Comment: Can you update the code where the dataframes are created? I get a syntax error if I try to  execute the code

Comment: sorry, it should work now

Comment: and you simpy want to compare the values of the corresponding rows? So, if the two rows with id `id_1_2` have the same value in column `sent_a.1` it should be set to `True`?

Comment: Also, is it on purpose that there are two rows with id `id_1_4`?

Comment: my original lists are much more than what is mentioned here, but they all follow the same pattern. so every list has two panda dataframes that have numeric values for all columns except for the 'ID' column where the values are as you see in the example

Comment: Q1: In the code that you provided to construct the dataframes, list_one[0] has two rows for the same ID `id_1_4`, and so is list_two[0]. Is that a mistake? Your expected output does not have two rows for `id_1_4`, but a row for `id_1_5` which does not exist in your original dataframes.

Comment: Q2: can you guarantee that each of the dataframes in your `list_one` and `list_two` does not have rows that share the same `ID`?

Comment: Q3: how to handle the case where an ID is found in one dataframe but not the other? Skip those?